# Vue/Javascript filter in deep object inside object array

Tags: javascript

I need to filter in deep the categories object inside an array, in an array with multiple objects. In an API call , I will have this array of objects with nested categories. I need to filter each object if it contains specific category id. This is the JSON -

```js
items_loop: [
  {
    ID: 1,
    name: "Item A",
    taxonomy: {
      categories: [
        {
          name: "Book",
          parent: 12,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
        {
          name: "Cover",
          parent: 4,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
        {
          name: "Other",
          parent: 15,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    name: "Item B",
    taxonomy: {
      categories: [
        {
          name: "Toys",
          parent: 16,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
        {
          name: "Book",
          parent: 12,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
        {
          name: "Other",
          parent: 15,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    name: "Item C",
    taxonomy: {
      categories: [
        {
          name: "Ext",
          parent: 6,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
        {
          name: "Cover",
          parent: 4,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
        {
          name: "Other",
          parent: 15,
          taxonomy: "category",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
]
```

I want to make a new array with object that contains only **"parent" : 15**, but how I can filter in deep this 3 object ? I tried with this, but it's not working

```js
function findInObjArray(array, value) {
  var found = []

  // Helper to search obj for value
  function findInObj(obj, value) {
    return Object.values(obj).some((v) =>
      // If v is an object, call recursively
      typeof v == "object" && v != "null"
        ? findInObj(v, value)
        : // If string, check if value is part of v
        typeof v == "string"
        ? v.indexOf(value) >= 0
        : // Check numbers, make NaN == NaN
        typeof v == "number"
        ? v === value || (isNaN(v) && isNaN(value))
        : // Otherwise look for strict equality: null, undefined, function, boolean
          v === value
    )
  }

  array.forEach(function (obj) {
    if (findInObj(obj, value)) found.push(obj)
  })

  return found
}
```

Comment: `condition ? val1 : val2 : val3` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this - filter arrays that is inside objects that is in your main array? You can iterate your array of object as you wish and do filter in cycle. Or use `map` method as in example below:

```js
const obj = [{
      ID: 1,
      name: 'Item A',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [{
            name: "Book",
            parent: 12,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Cover",
            parent: 4,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
        }]
      }
    },{
      ID: 2,
      name: 'Item B',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [{
            name: "Toys",
            parent: 16,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Book",
            parent: 12,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
        }]
      }
    },{
      ID: 3,
      name: 'Item C',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [{
            name: "Ext",
            parent: 6,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Cover",
            parent: 4,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
        }]
      }
}];
  
// Map and filter nested content
const res = obj.map(a => {
  a.taxonomy.categories = a.taxonomy.categories.filter(x => x.parent === 15);
  return a;
});
  
// Log
console.log(res)
```

Or if you mean you want to filter your main array to only contain object that has nested array with some value - then this is little modification of previous code

```js
const obj = [{
      ID: 1,
      name: 'Item A',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [{
            name: "Book",
            parent: 12,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Cover",
            parent: 4,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
        }]
      }
    },{
      ID: 2,
      name: 'Item B',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [{
            name: "Toys",
            parent: 16,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Book",
            parent: 12,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
        }]
      }
    },{
      ID: 3,
      name: 'Item C',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [{
            name: "Ext",
            parent: 6,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Cover",
            parent: 4,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },{
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
        }]
      }
}];
  
// Map and filter nested content
const res = obj.filter(a => {
  if((a.taxonomy.categories.filter(x => x.parent === 6)).length > 0) return a;
});
  
// Log
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should return an array of only `item` objects in which the nested `categories` array has been filtered for matches.

Note that:

- Only items containing at least 1 matching category are returned (meaning if an item didn't contain any matching categories, it will not be present in the output).
- Only matching categories are present in the output.
- If `categoryFilterFunc` returns no matches across all items and categories, the return value will be an empty array.

```js
const obj = {
  items_loop : [
    {
      ID: 1,
      name: 'Item A',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [
          {
            name: "Book",
            parent: 12,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },
          {
            name: "Cover",
            parent: 4,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },
          {
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },                                                                              
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      name: 'Item B',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [
          {
            name: "Toys",
            parent: 16,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },
          {
            name: "Book",
            parent: 12,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },
          {
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },                                                                              
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      name: 'Item C',
      taxonomy : {
        categories : [
          {
            name: "Ext",
            parent: 6,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },
          {
            name: "Cover",
            parent: 4,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },
          {
            name: "Other",
            parent: 15,
            taxonomy: "category",
          },             
        ]
      }
    },                      
  ]
};

function filterCategories(someObject, categoryFilterFunc) {
  return someObject.items_loop.reduce((accum, item) => {
    const filtered = item.taxonomy.categories.filter(categoryFilterFunc);
    if (filtered.length > 0) {
      // Creating a deep copy will have some performance impact (depending on
      // how many items and nested categories you need to iterate over)
      // but seems advisable for nested objects. Up to you if you
      // want to keep it.
      const deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
      deepCopy.taxonomy.categories = filtered;
      accum.push(deepCopy);
    }
    return accum;
  }, []);
}

const matchingItems = filterCategories(obj, categoryObj => 15 === categoryObj.parent);

console.log(matchingItems);
```

Comment: Thank you chillin, it work but in the Api call i've a lot of object. I prefeer to user the map method below. Thank you for help!